# Topology on the automorphism group of the fiber functor of a Galois category.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a Galois category with fiber functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{FinSets}$. Can we characterize the topology on $\text{Aut}(F)$ as the weakest topology that makes the action on all the $F(X)$ for $X \in \mathcal{C}$ continuous?